# Android dev - How to fix problems from following google maps tutorial

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

I'm new to android app development, and want to create an app that uses google maps. I followed the instructions straight from google here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

But I receive the following error in the log:

```
W/ResourceType( 1984): Bad XML block: header       size 84 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
W/ResourceType( 1984): Bad XML block: header size 85 or total size 5506544 is larger than data size 0
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\wrkspc\mapappexplore\res\menu\activity_main.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\eclipse\wrkspc\mapappexplore\res\menu\activity_map.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'android'
```

I followed the instructions perfectly as far as I know. Here's my code:

**MainActivity.java - The last line has the error "R cannot be resolved to a variable"**

```
package com.example.mapappexplore;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}
```

**Androidmanifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mapappexplore"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<!-- opengl -->
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true"/>


<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <permission
      android:name="com.example.mapappexplore.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapappexplore.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >



             <activity
             android:name="com.example.mapappexplore.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

                    <intent-filter> 
                         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
             <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAotiEiJVqDsCBYb3pHHhZUMlFz2eWSKTE"/>
             </activity>
</application>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Comment: Start by setting your build target (e.g., Properties > Android in Eclipse) to API Level 11 or higher, and set your `android:minSdkVersion` to 11 or higher, as your code assumes native API Level 11 fragments.

Comment: Changed to 11, It will send to my 4.2 device now, but crashes. I'd like the minimum sdk to be 8 anyway. Solutions to access maps on sdk 8 would be appreciated.

Comment: You will need to use `SupportMapFragment` in a `FragmentActivity` to work on versions earlier than API Level 11. Regarding the "but crashes" part, you will need to look at LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash.